# UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum not saving videos and returning error 0 abort with payload

Tags: ios, xcode, video, swift4, xcode9.2

This is my code to start the recording session.

```
var recordingDelegate:AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate? = self
        cameraSession.beginConfiguration()
        self.cameraSession.addOutput(videoFileOutput)
        cameraSession.commitConfiguration()
        let documentsURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
        filePath = documentsURL.appendingPathComponent("temp.mp4")


        videoFileOutput.startRecording(toOutputFileURL: filePath, recordingDelegate: recordingDelegate)
```

And this is the code to record the video after.

```
        self.videoFileOutput.stopRecording()
        UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum((filePath?.relativePath)!, nil, nil, nil)
        cameraSession.beginConfiguration()
        cameraSession.removeOutput(videoFileOutput)
        cameraSession.commitConfiguration()
```

This use to work before xcode 9 came out, but now when I try to stop my video it crashes my app and xcode throws the error Thread 8 signal SIGABART 0_abort_with_payload. My code has not changed from when xcode 8 for this section, but now it crashes. I cannot find the reason for this crash other than this error code. I suspect it has something to do with how I am saving the video. I have tried changing the appendingPathComponent, but it makes no difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are new permission strings you must fill in the info plist - with some of them new for Xcode 9 and iOS 11.
Check the following keys in your info plist exist:

- `NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription` (new)
- `NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription`
- `NSCameraUsageDescription`
- `NSMicrophoneUsageDescription`

You probably don't need all of them - but some of them for sure.
(I bet the first one which is newer is the Gotcha)